How to pass custom variables in supervisord
When I'm using supervisor to manage java processes, I want to pull some of them out into variables and make a template that can be generalized, but it doesn't seem to support this.
my code file is this:
[setting:variables]
server_port=
server_host=
server_prod=test
server_user=nginx
dir=
job_name=
module_name=

[usage:java]
java_home=/usr/local/jdk8/bin/java -jar
java_memory=-Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M
springboot_options=-Dspring.profiles.active=%(server_prod)s
java_path=%(setting:variables:dir)s/content/%(setting:variables:job_name)s/%(setting:variables:module_name)s.jar

; JMX Monitor
[monitor:jmx]
jmx_start=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
jmx_host=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=%(server_host)s
jmx_port=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1%(server_port)s
jmx_rmi_port=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1%(server_port)s
jmx_ssl=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
jmx_auth=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

[program:%(setting:variables:job_name)s-%(setting:variables:module_name)s]
command=%(usage:java:java_home)s \
        %(usage:java:java_memory)s \
        %(usage:java:springboot_options)s \
        %(usage:java:java_path)s \
;        %(monitor:jmx:jmx_start)s \
;        %(monitor:jmx:jmx_host)s \
;        %(monitor:jmx:jmx_port)s \
;        %(monitor:jmx:jmx_rmi_port)s \
;        %(monitor:jmx:jmx_ssl)s \
;        %(monitor:jmx:jmx_auth)s \
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=3
user=%(setting:variables:server_user)s
priority=999
redirect_stderr=true
stopasgroup=false
killasgroup=false
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=20MB
stdout_logfile_backups=20
stdout_logfile=%(setting:variables:dir)s/logs/%(setting:variables:job_name)s/%(setting:variables:module_name)s.log

Expecting to be able to successfully call the variables I passed in, e.g., job_name=test, module_name=test, when I run the supervisorctl update command a test-test item will be added.

If I am right you want to pass environment variables into the supervisor config file?
